# Local Date java 8 used in SQL

Tags: java, sql, date, localdate

How to create a SQL table with correct data when I use LocalDate?

Here is my query

```
CREATE TABLE USER(EMAIL VARCHAR(255), STARTDATE DATE, ENDDATE DATE);
```

and in my class I have this properties

```
private String email;
private LocalDate startDate;
private LocalDate endDate;
```

Comment: what is the problem here?

Comment: sql is empty that, maybe i have to convert java.time.LocalDate with java.sql.Date, but I don't have any idea how to do this

Comment: can you show us your code where you persist data to database please?

Comment: beside are you using simple jdbc, JPA, spring data what are you using exactly!!

Comment: Voting to close as unclear. No specific question is asked. Create a table? Or parse a result set? If the latter, this has been addressed already on many existing Questions and Answers showing `ResultSet::getObject`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public List<HRVacantionUser> listVacantionGoogleUsers(List<GoogleUser> allGoogleUsers){
   LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
   List<HRVacantionUser> collect = allGoogleUsers.stream()
      .map(user ->
          new HRVacantionUser(user.getPrimaryEmail(), date, date.plusDays(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 5))))
      .collect(toList());
        return collect;
```

Here i want to set random date to user from current date to random date